# What is the proper way of chaining multiple Middlewares in Next Js

Tags: next.js, middleware

Oh, i am so confused on how should I chain multiple middlewares in next js. Suppose I have two pages /dashboard and /admin , both of these exist in pages directory. In /dashboard , I am suppose to check if user is authenticated whereas in admin , I am suppose to check if user has an admin role.

So based on the documentation, I am suppose to create a middleware.js file inside src directory (also the same level as pages directory)

Following is my code

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

async function isAuth(req) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  if (token === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return token;
}

async function isAdmin(token) {
  const { role } = token;
  return role === "admin" ? true : false;
}

function redirectToHomePage(req) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  url.pathname = "/";
  return NextResponse.redirect(url);
}

export async function middleware(req) {
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/random") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin")
  ) {
    //check if you are authenticated
    const token = await isAuth(req);
    if (token) {
        //check if you are admin
      const admin = await isAdmin(token);
      return admin
        ? res
        : new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "You are not an admin" }),
            { status: 401, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
          );
    }
    return redirectToHomePage(req);
  }
  if (path === "/dashboard") {
    const result = await isAuth(req);
    if (result) {
      return res;
    }
    return redirectToHomePage(req);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Following code does work and get me what I want but I can see this getting pretty messy quite soon when the codebase gets larger.

So my question if this is the correct way or is there a better way to do things ?

Thank you.

Comment: According to this article: [How to Chain Multiple Middleware Functions in NextJS](https://reacthustle.com/blog/how-to-chain-multiple-middleware-functions-in-nextjs), you need to write your own middleware that will stack the other middleware, there is no builtin feature to combine middlewares.